# Taylor Series of $ \cfrac{x}{1+x} $ at $ x = -2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the taylor series for the following:

$$ \cfrac{x}{1+x} \ \text{ at } \ x = -2 $$

The following are my steps:

$$ \cfrac{x}{1+x} = 1 - \cfrac{1}{1+x} \ \text{ (by long division) } $$

Taylor series of $ \cfrac{1}{1+x} $ at $ x = 0, $
$$ \begin{align} \cfrac{1}{1+x} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n(x)^n}\end{align} $$

Taylor series of $ \cfrac{1}{1+x} $ at $ x = -2, $
$$ \begin{align} \cfrac{1}{1+(x+2)} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n(x+2)^n}\end{align} $$

Taylor series of $ \cfrac{x}{1+x} $ at $ x = -2, $
$$ \begin{align}
\cfrac{x}{1+x}
&= 1 - \cfrac{1}{1+x} \\
&= 1 - \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n(x+2)^n} \\ 
&= 1 - \left(\cfrac{1}{1+(-2)} + \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n(x+2)^n}\right) \\ 
&= 2 - \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n(x+2)^n} 
\end{align}
$$

Somehow, the answer is: 
$ 2 + \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(x+2)^n}  $

I know that my last block of working seems wrong. But I just cannot think of anything else. Could someone please advise me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{x}{-1+x+2}=\frac{-(x+2)+2}{1-(x+2)}=1+\frac{1}{1-(x+2)}.$$
Now use the result: for $|z|<1$ then
$\displaystyle \cfrac{1}{1-z} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{ z^n}$.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get the answer. But, may I ask why the summation index for the answer has to be 1? Is there an error that occurs when n = 0?

Comment: @LanceHAOH You can also write the answer as $1 +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(x+2)^n}$. In the answer written as $2 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(x+2)^n}$ it is more evident the first term of the expansion: 2.